# Defaulting the 12/24 hour settings in an app to the users device set value

Tags: android

I have an app that allows a user to choose a time in their preferences. I want to display these times in 12 or 24 hour format based on the users device time preferences. Is there a way I can access this device value? I will then set the 12/24 hour flag on the TimePicker appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

I found this static method which returns the users 12/24 hour preference. I tested it using a German locale and an Irish one. 12/24 hour nature of the app is set appropriately.

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)
```